# not able to find "localconfig\atg\dynamo\service\jdbc" inside ATG\DAS 6.3.0 folder

Tags: atg-dynamo

I am trying to configure my local atg dynamo server 6.3.0. I am unable to find out 
localconfig\atg\dynamo\service\jdbc. Inside my ATG\DAS6.3.0\home.

Can you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

Try ATG/home/servers/*<your_server_name>*/localconfig/atg/dynamo/service/jdbc.